# AWS - Signing a Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

Hi I am trying to follow this tutorial below of signing a Lambda Function due to the fact I was getting an error in my jenkins Build which stated

```
error getting Lambda Function (watchtower_backend_testing) code signing config AccessDeniedException: 
    status code: 403
```

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-code-signing-a-trust-and-integrity-control-for-aws-lambda/

In the tutorial, to Start a Signing Job, they are linking to a Lambda function in an S3 bucket. My question is, how to I export my current Lambda function into my S3 bucket? Tks

Comment: Hey @shellac2020, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this issue by pinning to last version of the provider:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = "<= 3.16.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you, this is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Jenkins runs with an IAM role that has the proper policy attached, which allows it to perform Lambda API actions related to code signing config.

A few of them that you need in your policy:

```
"lambda:CreateCodeSigningConfig",
"lambda:UpdateCodeSigningConfig",
"lambda:GetCodeSigningConfig",
"lambda:GetFunctionEventInvokeConfig",
```